# Google Apps javascript iterating through multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm relatively new to customizing Google sheets and only learning javascript.
I'm trying to create a custom function that will search for a value in an array and return a string (something like vlookup).

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the value checked against multiple arrays. I wrote the below but for some reason, it checks only first element of the array (it did work but stopped for some reason and I cannot figure out why as I don't think I changed anything).

The second part will be trickier still, how to make it work against multiple arrays... I was thinking to create an array:
depots = [depot1,depot2...] and then change the code to "depots.length in for loop but even 1 array proves to be problematic.

```js
var depot1 = ["device1", "device2", "device3"];
var depot1 = ["device1", "device2", "device3"];

function _depot(value) {
  if (value) {
    var depotCheckCase = value.toUpperCase();

    for (var i = 0; i < depot1.length; i++) {
      if (depotCheckCase == depot1[i]) {
        return "Depot 1";
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Warning to potential answerers: Google Apps Script is **not** JavaScript. It's very, very similar, along the lines of ES3 plus a bit. It does not have most modern JavaScript features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only checks the first entry because you have `return` in both branches of your `if`/`else`, so no matter what, the first loop iteration will terminate the function.

Instead, move the `return false;` to the end, outside of the loop.

A couple of other issues:

- You're declaring the same variable twice. Your second `var depot1 = ...` ends up being just an assignment (but since the array it's assigning has the same entries as the first one, you may not notice).
- You're forcing the value to check to upper case, but not doing the same to the entry you're checking against.

Addressing all of those:

```js
var depot1 = ["device1", "device2", "device3"];

function _depot(value) {
  if (value) {
    var depotCheckCase = value.toUpperCase();

    for (var i = 0; i < depot1.length; i++) {
      if (depotCheckCase == depot1[i].toUpperCase()) {
        return "Depot 1";
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(_depot("device2")); // "Depot 1"
console.log(_depot("device8")); // false
```

> Any idea how can I combine it with checking against second/third array?

You have two options:

1. Additional loops (simplest).
2. Finding the length of the longest array, using that as the loop max, and checking against `undefined` before comparing. Since `[n]` on an array when `n` is greater than or equal to the length will give you `undefined`, you can check that before doing the `toUpperCase`.

Here's that second one:

```js
var depot1 = ["device1", "device2", "device3"];
var depot2 = ["device4", "device5"];
var depot3 = ["device6", "device7", "device8", "device9"];

function _depot(value) {
  if (value) {
    var depotCheckCase = value.toUpperCase();
    var max = Math.max(depot1.length, depot2.length, depot3.length);
    var entry;
    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
      entry = depot1[i];
      if (entry !== undefined && depotCheckCase === entry.toUpperCase()) {
        return "Depot 1";
      }
      entry = depot2[i];
      if (entry !== undefined && depotCheckCase === entry.toUpperCase()) {
        return "Depot 2";
      }
      entry = depot3[i];
      if (entry !== undefined && depotCheckCase === entry.toUpperCase()) {
        return "Depot 3";
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(_depot("device2"));  // "Depot 1"
console.log(_depot("device8"));  // "Depot 3"
console.log(_depot("device5"));  // "Depot 2"
console.log(_depot("device10")); // false
```

You could give yourself an array of arrays and do that in a loop rather than repeating the logic. I leave that as an exercise for the reader. :-)